# Are Xcode module names case sensitive?

Tags: xcode

I have 4 Cocoa Touch Framework projects: **storage**, **model**, **Storage**, **Model**. I tried to separate contracts and implementations to provide Inversion Of Control architecture principle. **storage** contains protocols, **Storage** contains implementations of **storage** protocols. There is analogy situation with **model** and **Model**.

When I tried to import **storage** to **Storage** I had the following error as result:

> Cannot load underlying module for 'storage'

And the same situation with importing **model** to **Model**.

But there is no problem with importing **storage** to **Model** and **model** to **Storage**. Looks like module naming is case insensitive. But I can import both modules **storage** and **Storage** to **Model**. And I can't understand politics of modules naming. 'Cannot load underlying module for' - says nothing about what is wrong.

Is modules names in Xcode case sensitive? How to import **storage** into **Storage**?

---

This question is result of my real development problem. For clear reproduce I describe problem in simplified example step by step.

1) Open Xcode -> Create new Xcode project -> Single View App (Product Name = App, Directory = app in root of case sensate volume)

```
> diskutil info dev

...  
File System Personality:   Case-sensitive APFS.  
...
```

2) Xcode -> File -> New Project -> Cocoa Touch Framework (Product Name = **X**, Directory = App, Add to = App, Group = App)

3) Xcode -> File -> New Project -> Cocoa Touch Framework (Product Name = **x**, Directory = App, Add to = App, Group = App)

4) Xcode -> File -> New Project -> Cocoa Touch Framework (Product Name = **Y**, Directory = App, Add to = App, Group = App)

5) Add to **x** new swift file Src.swift with code: `protocol XProtocol { }`

6) Compile **x** - Succeeded

7) Add to **X** new swift file Src.swift with code: `class XClass { }`

8) Compile **X** - Succeeded

7) Add to **Y** new swift file Src.swift with code: `class YClass { }`

8) Compile **Y** - Succeeded

9) Add `import X` into top of Src.swift of **Y**

10) Compile **Y** - Succeeded

11) Replace `import X` with `import x` in top of Src.swift of **Y**

12) Compile **Y** - Failed. Error:

> Cannot load module 'X' as 'x'

13) Add `import x` into top of of Src.swift of **X**

14) Compile **X** - Failed. Error:

> Cannot load module 'X' as 'x'

15) Add `import X` into top of of Src.swift of **x**

16) Compile **x** - Failed. Error:

> Cannot load underlying module for 'X'

This reproduce gives me other results, but I continue to don't understand politics of modules naming. It looks like module names should be case insensitive unique. But it is by the fact of impossibility. Errors are unclear. Does apple provide some docs about this?

---

**Note** (01.11.19)

Problem is missing if instead of Cocoa Touch Frameworks use Static Libraries. I can import **x** into **X** and both **x** and **X** into **Y** without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices use case sensitive file naming, but the simulator and Xcode are running on your Mac which is not case sensitive. And when you ask to load a module represented by a framework, you are effectively naming a file (the framework as folder). So I would guess that the problem you're having is just a consequence of the fact that filenames (pathnames, file URLs, etc.) are case-insensitive on the Mac where you are trying to compile this code.

Comment: I created virtual case sensitive volume specially for development. And my source codes is in this volume.

Comment: Maybe the cause of this problem is that Xcode (is installed on case insensitive volume) creates some temporary folders (paths) based on source code module name when trying to compile.

Comment: I have no idea. You are in charge of where Xcode puts its intermediate folders during a build.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this situation with new project. Process details and results I added into question description.

Comment: The problem is actual only for frameworks. See my last note in the question.